# Eclipse - Internal Web Browser Path Incorrect

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I'm just starting out with PHP development and I am having some trouble running my code in Eclipse with PDT.

In preferences I set up my default PHP server with a Base URL of `http://localhost` and a Local Web Root of `/Users/myUserName/Sites`. With these settings, when I run a php file in the Internal Web Browser, the URL Eclipse loads is in the format `http://localhost/fileName.php` and always ends on a "Not Found" error page.

When I access the files from my browser, I find I need to use the format `http://localhost/~myUserName/fileName.php`, and when I add this into the Eclipse browser it displays correctly. How can I get Eclipse to add in the "~myUserName/" term by default? I tried adding it to the end of the Base URL, but it wouldn't let me add anything after localhost.